# How does one update one file in a snap?

Tags: snap

In the `snap` for application skanlite one configuration file `/snap/skanlite/current/etc/sane.d/genesys.conf` is either out-of-date or does not have the needed settings.  How does one updated or override it?

Comment: The the apt version work for you? `sudo apt install skanlite`

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the snap version is problematic, you can use the apt version. `apt` provides version 2.1.0.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo apt install skanlite
```

Answer (score 1):

To update or reload the snap it is use the `refresh` option.

```
sudo snap refresh skanlite --edge
```

However, the above command may not update the `skanlite` application since it has not been updated since 2019-04-30

```
snap info skanlite
name:      skanlite
summary:   image scanner based on the KSane backend
publisher: KDE✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/skanlite
contact:   https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=neon&component=Snaps
license:   GPL-2.0+
description: |
  skanlite is a terminal based on an electronic game released in 1978
  Skanlite is a small and simple scanner application (based on KDE
  Frameworks) which allows easy scanning of images with an attached scanner.
  Through the KSane backend, it can access a wide variety of different
  scanner models.
snap-id: t44B2I4AeVBXO7Lbdg7pV9eN7JpvPq6w
channels:
  latest/stable:    –                                 
  latest/candidate: –                                 
  latest/beta:      –                                 
  latest/edge:      master+cb382f8 2019-04-30 (7) 9MB -
```